# Livewire nestable is resetting order on drop

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

using the following library to add sorting and nesting `https://www.hesamurai.com/nested-sort/latest`, I'm also using the `pre-rendered` list option to populate the items (`https://www.hesamurai.com/nested-sort/latest/pre-rendered`).

Now my html structure looks like the following:

```
    <div x-data class="pageContent__content__components mb10">
                    <span class="subTitle">Menu items</span>
                    <ol x-init="initSort($refs.draggable)" x-ref='draggable' id="draggable"
                        class='nested-sort nested-sort--enabled'>
                        @foreach($navigation->navigation_items as $item)
                            <li wire:key='{{ $item->id }}' draggable='true'
                                data-id="{{ $item->id }}"> {{ $item->navigatable->page_name ?? $item->navigatable->blog_title }}
                                <i wire:click="showAlert('{{ $item->id }}')"
                                   class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
                            </li>


                            @if($item->children->count() > 0)
                                <ol data-id="{{ $item->id }}">
                                    @foreach($item->children as $child)
                                        <li draggable='true'
                                            data-id="{{ $child->navigatable->id  }}"> {{ $child->navigatable->page_name ?? $child->navigatable->blog_title }}
                                            <i wire:click="showAlert('{{ $child->navigatable->id }}')"
                                               class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
                                        </li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ol>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </ol>
                </div>
```

With the scripts being included at the bottom of the page

```
@push('scripts')
    @once
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nested-sort@5/dist/nested-sort.umd.min.js"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function initSort(ref) {
                return {
                    nested: new NestedSort({
                        el: ref,

                        actions: {
                            onDrop: function(data) {
                                @this.
                                call('saveMenuOrder', data);
                            },
                        },
                    }),
                };
            }
        </script>
    @endonce
@endpush
```

Now, adding and removing items to the list works as intended, but reordering or nesting any item causes livewire to reset the list to it's initial state.

If I where to add a `wire:ignore` to the `<ol>` that technically fixes the issue of livewire updating the DOM, but that also means that, when adding or removing items it no longer updates the list without manually refreshing the page.

My backend component looks like this:

```
  // the model containing the items to be displayed (via a HasMany relation)
  public NavigationModel $navigation;


  // the method that is called everytime the onDrop action fires (the $data array contains the new order of elements)

  public function saveMenuOrder(array $data): void
  {
    foreach ($data as $menuItem) {
      $menuItemObject = $this->navigation->navigation_items->find(
        $menuItem['id']
      );

      $menuItemObject->order = $menuItem['order'];
      if (isset($menuItem['parent'])) {
        $menuItemObject->parent_id = $menuItem['parent'];
      } else {
        $menuItemObject->parent_id = null;
      }
      $menuItemObject->save();
    }
  }
```

And that's basically it for the component, all I want is for livewire to update the list without messing up the DOM elements created by the library.

any ideas?

alpineJS is also installed, if that's a better solution that's also accepted.

thanks!

--- Edit

What I currenly have:

I converted the laravel foreach to an alpine x-for:

```
  <div class="pageContent__content" style="grid-area: unset">
                <div x-data='initSort($refs.draggable)'
                     wire:ignore
                     class="pageContent__content__components mb10">
                    <span class="subTitle">Menu items</span>
                    <ol class='nested-sort' x-ref='draggable' id="draggable">
                        <template x-for="item in items">
                            <li draggable="true" :data-id='item.id'>
                                <div class='nested-sort-item'>
                                    <div class='nested-sort-item__text' x-text='item.text' />
                                    <div class='nested-sort-item__actions'>
                                        <button type='button' class='nested-sort-item__actions__button'
                                                @click='$wire.showAlert(item.id)'
                                        >
                                            <i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </template>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and rewrote the init function:

```
            function initSort(ref) {
                return {
                    navigation_items: @js($this->navigation_items),

                    get items() {
                        return this.navigation_items;
                    },

                    init() {
                        new NestedSort({
                            el: ref,

                            actions: {
                                onDrop: function(data) {

                                },
                            },
                        });
                    },
                };
            }
```

Now I can't seem to figure out how to access the `navigation_items` inside of my `onDrop` action, simply using `this.navigation_items` or `this.items` console.logs undefined.

Comment: When dealing with external libraries like this one we usually use alpinejs with livewire. What I would do it's start the x-data with `x-data="{navigation_items: {{ $navigationItems }} }" and use the x-for to iterate the x-data (removing the laravel @foreach). Then on your `onDrop` function I would update the navigation_items from the x-data. Let me know if my comments make sense to you, otherwise I can try to mount a POC for this on the weekend.

Comment: Hey, so far I managed to convert the laravel foreach to a alpine x-for, but so far I can't seem to figure out how to update the navigation_items array when the onDrop event happens. See the edit for what I currently have.

Comment: Are you trying to use `this.navigation_items` inside of the `onDrop` function? Please try to create an instance of alpine on the first line of your `init()` function using `let ap = this;` then inside of your `onDrop` function you can call `console.log(ap.navigation_items)`, this will probably fix your current problem.